# HTTP/1.1 body length calculate

Tags: http

The web server **does not close** the connection after sending a 401 Unauthorized like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n
Date: Fri, 23 Nov 2018 10:50:52 GMT\r\n
Server: DNVRS-Webs\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Content-Type: text/html\r\n
Connection: close\r\n
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="DVRNVRDVS", domain="::", qop="auth", nonce="e7db4eb94dd16ef9f0ff8c56d349ca94:1542970252377", opaque="", algorithm="MD5", stale="FALSE"\r\n
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="DVRNVRDVS"\r\n
\r\n
\r\n
```

According to [RFC7230 3.3.3 Message Body Length](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3)

> 7. Otherwise, this is a response message without a declared message
>    body length, so the message body length is determined by the
>    number of octets received prior to the server closing the
>    connection.

Is this behavior valid?

**Edit**:
What's more, another web server doesn't have the last `\r\n` line, does that matter?

**Edit**: According to [6.6 Tear-down](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.6) part:

> A server that sends a "close" connection option MUST initiate a close
> of the connection (see below) after it sends the response containing
> "close".  The server MUST NOT process any further requests received
> on that connection.

What does this `initiate a close of the connection` mean?

Does this

> To avoid the TCP reset problem, servers typically close a connection
> in stages

means that the web server needn't close the connection immediately?